# Manually Rotating UIViews Instead of Autorotation

Tags: ios, uiview, rotation

In iOS, what is the proper way to manually rotate your views?  I have a lot of custom rotation animations and I don't want my view to autorotate at all.

Right now, I'm doing this...

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return interfaceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait;
}
```

Then, I'm doing this and responding to orientation changes as needed:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(orientationChanged:) name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil];
```

Everything is working fine, except... When I try to present action sheets, a MailViewController, etc, they all display in portrait orientation :(

How can I have my view know that, while I don't want it to autorotate, it is in fact responding to orientation notifications which I am handling manually?

Edit:  To clarify, it's not that my rotations aren't working, it's that when I present a UIActionSheet, it assumes I must be in portrait (even when I've manually rotated so that I'm not), and it displays incorrectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)];` when you manualy rotate your view

Comment: Wow awesome, thanks a bunch! Funny story... I recently did a ton of code reorganization/cleanup and, come to think of it (and confirmed by my git history), I used to have this line in my code but deleted it because I couldn't remember why it was there!  I will not forget again the purpose of that line of code haha.

Comment: (especially since it comes with a detailed comment this time around)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can call a method from within shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation.
for example:

```
    - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation (UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    if (interfaceOrientation != UIDeviceOrientationPortrait)
        [self theActionYouWantToPerform]

    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return interfaceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but the problem isn't that my rotation's aren't working.  It's that my UIView doesn't realize it's even been rotated (since I'm returning "interfaceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait"), so UIActionSheets and the MailComposer, which automatically display in the orientation of the parent view, always display in portrait, even if I manually rotated my view so that it doesn't LOOK like it is in portrait.

Answer (score 0):

The line reported by Anton K

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)];
```

Works me fine!. Is IT just the element that rested me when I want to MANUALLY rotate an UIView of an UIViewController using the CGAFFineTransformMakeRotation method for rotating the view PI/2 radians.

This line, set the ORIENTATION of the STATUS BAR to the *(UIInterfaceOrientation)* you want, for making the perfect appearance of an UIView "manually" rotated to the *(UIInterfaceOrientation)* I want.

In consequence, this line also makes ***UIMessageView***'s further presented, appears it in the *(UIInterfaceOrientation)* you indicated.